# visual studio relentlessly prompts to trust the IIS Express SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

Every time I launch a SSL web site, Visual Studio prompts "The project is configured to use SSL...would you like to trust the IIS Express SSL cert?"  Clicking Yes in response and checking "Don't not ask me again" does not unfortunately deter Visual Studio from prompting again next time the site is launched.  I tried importing the IIS cert into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store manually following the approached outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).  But VS is still prompting on each successive launch.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what the *correct* way to fix this is... Adding a local cert to Trusted Root doesn't feel right to me.

I prefer the method provided by [Vossekop's Blog](http://www.vosseburcht.com/?p=97)

Add this value to the registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects]
"HideTrustIISCertificatePrompt"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: This works for VS2015 also, just have to change `12.0` to `14.0` in the registry path.

Comment: For VS2017 change 12.0 to 15.0_65c25b92

Comment: There is no web projects folder for VS 16 (VS 2019).  So the new key and value can't be added without also adding a new folder.  Just wondering if there isn't a way to do that?  I'm no registry expert so didn't want to just act out on this notion.

Answer (score 1):

The technique outlined in the referenced post is to export the IIS Express certificate from the Personal store and then import it into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.  While manually exporting and then importing didn't work for me, simply dragging the cert from Personal store to the Trusted Root's store did work.  Go figure!  And this behavior is repeatable.

Comment: Warning! It only works until you reboot the machine. Afterwards HTTPS is broken on IIS express. I'm still trying to fix it.